# What permissions are needed on an SQS queue in order to be able to receive notifications from SES over SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

My scenario: Send mail using SES and receive delivery information over SNS into an SQS queue. What permissions does that queue need to have?

I found that if I don't grant any permissions at all the notifications do not arrive. When I grant `Everyone` permission the notifications do arrive but that is unsafe.

What should permissions should I set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to give the SNS Queue permission to call the `sqs:SendMessage` API Call

To do this, you add a policy to your SQS Queue, that allows all principals, on the condition that their ARN is your SNS's ARN, effectively locking down that particular call from your SNS topic.

You can find an example below - replace the Resource and SourceArn as required.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"MySQSPolicy001",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:MyQueue",
      "Condition":{
        "ArnEquals":{
          "aws:SourceArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:MyTopic"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html

Comment: The `SourceArn` seems key. `Action` can be anything which is simpler I think.